# Generalized Pauli matrices for spin $s>1/2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory

What is the general form of the Pauli matrices for a $3\times 3$ matrix (spin $s=1$)?  Do these generalized Pauli matrices satisfy all the properties exhibited by the Pauli $2\times 2$ matrices, such as being Hermitian? Furthermore, is it possible to represent all Hermitian $3\times 3$ matrices using these generalized Pauli matrices?

[image: Here]

Comment: What property of the Pauli matrices are you trying to generalise? Their relation to the matrix representation of the spin-$1/2$ operators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Charlie asks, the Pauli matrices have several properties, which generalize in [different manners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices).  They certainly, together with the identity, provide a complete basis for 2×2 matrices, but they are also hermitian. If Hermiticity is important to you, you generalize them as in the link provided, that is along the Gell-Mann matrices' route for 3×3 matrices.

However, a far more tasteful and systematic basis is J J Sylvester's 1882 one of *clock and shift matrices*  for *d×d* ***unitary*** matrices which you should know about, anyway. They are not hermitean in general, but they are more systematic (some would say "analytic in d").

For $ω= \exp(2iπ/d)$,  a root of unity not equal to 1.  The sum  of all roots annuls, $1 + \omega + \cdots + \omega ^{d-1} = 0 $, so integer indices may   be cyclically identified mod *d*.

The *shift matrix* is defined as
$$
\Sigma _1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 0     & 1\\
1      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 0     & 0\\
0      & 1      & 0      & \cdots & 0     & 0\\
0      & 0      & 1      & \cdots & 0     & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\
0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 1     & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
 $$
and the  *clock matrix* as
$$ 
\Sigma _3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1      & 0      & 0        & \cdots & 0\\
0      & \omega & 0        & \cdots & 0\\
0      & 0      & \omega^2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots\\
0      & 0      & 0        & \cdots & \omega^{d-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
These matrices generalize $σ_1$   and the diagonal $σ_3$,  respectively.
Since Pauli matrices describe  quaternions, Sylvester dubbed the higher-dimensional analogs "nonions", "sedenions", etc.

These two matrices are also the cornerstone of Weyl's celebrated  *quantum mechanical dynamics in finite-dimensional vector spaces*    The clock matrix amounts to the exponential of position in a "clock" of *d* hours, and the shift matrix is just the translation operator in that cyclic vector space, so the exponential of the momentum. They are (finite-dimensional)  representations of the corresponding elements of the  Heisenberg group on a *d* -dimensional Hilbert space.

The following relations echo and generalize those of the Pauli matrices:
$\Sigma_1^d = \Sigma_3^d = I$,
and the braiding relation,
$\Sigma_3 \Sigma_1 = \omega \Sigma_1 \Sigma_3 = e^{2\pi i / d} \Sigma_1 \Sigma_3$, and can be rewritten as
$\Sigma_3 \Sigma_1 \Sigma_3^{d-1} \Sigma_1^{d-1} = \omega ~$.

The complete family of $d^2$   unitary (but non-Hermitian) independent matrices
$$
\left(\Sigma_1\right)^k \left(\Sigma_3\right)^j = \sum_{m=0}^{d-1} |m+k\rangle \omega^{jm} \langle m|,
$$
then provides Sylvester's well-known trace-orthogonal  basis for  $\mathfrak{gl} (d,ℂ)$, known as "nonions" $\mathfrak{gl} (3,ℂ)$, "sedenions"  $\mathfrak{gl} (4,ℂ)$, etc... Since all indices are defined cyclically mod *d*,  $\mathrm{tr}\Sigma_1^j \Sigma_3^k \Sigma_1^m \Sigma_3^n = \omega^{km} d ~\delta_{j+m,0}  \delta_{k+n,0}$

Comment: would you have the exact reference to Sylvester’s work where he introduces the clock-and-shift matrices?

Comment: Sure: ref 2 in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Clifford_algebra), except somebody has garbled the first link there.  In any case,  Sylvester, J. J. (1882), A word on Nonions, Johns Hopkins University Circulars, vol. I, pp. 241–2,; ibid II (1883) 46; ibid III (1884) 7–9. Summarized in The Collected Mathematics Papers of James Joseph Sylvester (Cambridge University Press, 1909) v III .
[Link](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/aas8085.0003.001/664?rgn=full+text;view=pdf;q1=nonions),

Comment: and [Link](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/AAS8085.0004.001/165?cite1=Sylvester;cite1restrict=author;rgn=full+text;view=pdf). With Cayley and Poincare, he is one of my heroes...

Comment: Thank you Sir!  ZtH

Answer (score 0):

Pauli matrices (plus the identity matrix) are just a choice of matrices that allow decomposition of an arbitrary 2-by-2 matrix - i.e. a matrix with 4 independent parameters. One could choose them differently, so this particular choice is more due to the tradition and the fact that all the three matrices are already Hermitian. It is not uncommon to use $\hat{\sigma}_\pm$ instead of $\sigma_{x,y}$.

For 3-by-3 case one needs in principle 9 matrices, one of which can be the identity matrix. They also can be all chosen Hermitian. However, one will have more freedom than in the 2-by-2 case. This freedom might be further restricted by a particular application - e.g., describing certain type of rotations.

Comment: How can I write desired matrix with pauli matrices 3_3?you mean it’s  impossible?

Comment: I mean that there are multiple choices, and no widely accepted convention.